# How to move a gameObject smoothly when mouse drag only in one direction and when mouse release snap to grid(Unity)

Tags: pointers, unity-game-engine, mouseevent, game-center, raycasting

I am working on a little game. Till now I manage to move the block in either x or Y direction. Right now I am just snapping the block to the grid. I want to make it smoothly follow the mouse and when I release the object should snap to nearby grid. I am not god with calculating screen and world position. Hope some experienced person guides me. These are Quard, not the UI element.

This is inside update

```
 if (dragging) { //if dragging shoot raycast
   if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition),
       out hit, Mathf.Infinity, blockLayer)) {
     Debug.Log("isnide dragging");
     //Parent GameObject
     //initialize empty obj and make it parent
     tempParentObj = ParentGameObjectWithNewObject();

     //calculation for movement
     if (previousPart != null) {

       Vector3 previousPos = hit.point;
       Vector3 worldPos = hit.point;
       worldPos.z = adjustedHeight;

       worldPos.x = Mathf.Round(hit.point.x);

       worldPos.y = Mathf.Round(hit.point.y);

       //Code to restrict block to change its X and y pos at the same time.
       if (worldPos.y != previousPart.transform.position.y && worldPos.x != previousPart.transform.position.x) {
         Debug.Log("returning");
         return;
       }
       //parent object of block move
       tempParentObj.transform.position = worldPos;

     }
   }
```

Progress till now

[image]

What I want to achieve

[image]

Thank you for reading this. Any reference will be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Set the object to the mouse's position, then when the mouse is released [do some math on it](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/util/MathHelper.cs#L69-L87).

Comment: Thank you so much Draco, Snapping is easy. I am able to do that now also. But I am not able to move the block with a mouse position on a single axis. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Moving on a single axis is done by taking the first movement that happened, figuring out which axis its on (deltax > deltay?), remembering that until the mouse is released, and then zeroing out the other axis during the movement.

Comment: Thank you so much Draco, Now I am able to move And snap on a single axis. Thanks.